# C++ cascaded operator[] to operator() parameter list?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, metaprogramming, syntactic-sugar

I have a class with `operator()` like this:

```
struct S
{
    int operator()(int a, int b, int c, int d);
};
```

Example usage:

```
S s;
int i = s(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I need my users to be able to use an alternate syntax:

```
int i = s[1][2][3][4]; // equivalent to calling s(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I know I need to add `S::operator[](int a)` and that it needs to return a helper object.  But beyond that it all gets a bit complex and I have a feeling that I am reinventing the wheel since other libraries (e.g. multidimensional arrays) probably already offer similar interface.

Ideally I'd just use an existing library to achieve this goal.  Failing that, how can I achieve my goal with the most generic code?

**Edit:** ideally I'd like to achieve this without any runtime penalty on a modern optimizing compiler.

Comment: Your helper object's operator[] needs to return another helper object, etc.

Comment: "with most generic code" ha, a metaprogramming challenge :) Let me try

Comment: Really, just keep the `operator()`... it'll get *very* nasty with those helper structs...

Comment: Those other multidimensional array libraries won't return `void` from their multi-[] expressions. Even if their helper objects do ultimately call an n-parameter function, they'll expect it to return a reference. So I wouldn't bet on being able to re-use much. I pity everyone involved, most of all the person who thought that `s[1][2][3][4]` looks like a reasonable void expression!

Comment: @paperjam: the reason Kos is asking might have to do with `std::bind`. In which case what are your thoughts on `boost::bind`?

Comment: I was looking at `boost::bind` but assumed I need access to its internals to set the individual parameters separately.  Absolutely want to use any Boost libraries if they help.

Comment: @SteveJessop no, I was considering to use var-arg templates because a generic solution should be parametrised on the number of parameters to  operator(). @paperjam If there was an `operator()(int* args)` or `operator()(const int (&args)[N])` then I could do it I think

Comment: A templated `operator()(const int (&args)[N])` sounds reasonable because this could be specialized with `N=4` to call the `operator()` in my question.

Comment: Btw, just edited the question to add a little about runtime penalty.  It would be nice to achieve this without any runtime overhead but answers which don't compile away to nothing still very welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go!

First of all, the code is kind of messy- I have to accumulate the argument values as we go, and the only way I could think of (at least in C++03) is to pass the immediate indices set around as arrays.

I have checked this on G++ 4.5.1 (Windows / MinGW) and I confirm that on -O3 the call:

`s[1][2][3][4];`

yields the same assembler code as:

`s(1,2,3,4);`

So - no runtime overhead if your compiler is smart with optimisations. *Good job, GCC team!*

Here goes the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned Count>
struct PartialResult
{
    static const int IndicesRemembered = Count-1-N;
    T& t;
    int args[IndicesRemembered];
    PartialResult(T& t, int arg, const int* rest) : t(t) {
        for (int i=0; i<IndicesRemembered-1; ++i) {
            args[i] = rest[i];
        }
        if (IndicesRemembered>0) args[IndicesRemembered-1] = arg;
    }
    PartialResult<T, N-1, Count> operator[](int k) {
        return PartialResult<T, N-1, Count>(t, k, args);
    }
};

template<typename T, unsigned Count>
struct PartialResult<T, 0, Count>
{
    static const int IndicesRemembered = Count-1;
    T& t;
    int args[IndicesRemembered];
    PartialResult(T& t, int arg, const int* rest) : t(t) {
        for (int i=0; i<IndicesRemembered-1; ++i) {
            args[i] = rest[i];
        }
        if (IndicesRemembered>0) args[IndicesRemembered-1] = arg;
    }
    void operator[](int k) {
        int args2[Count];
        for (int i=0; i<Count-1; ++i) {
            args2[i] = args[i];
        }
        args2[Count-1] = k;
        t(args2);
    }
};

template<typename T, unsigned Count>
struct InitialPartialResult : public PartialResult<T, Count-2, Count> {
    InitialPartialResult(T& t, int arg)
        : PartialResult<T, Count-2, Count>(t, arg, 0) {}
};

struct C {

    void operator()(const int (&args)[4]) {
        return operator()(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    }
    void operator()(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
       std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
    }
    InitialPartialResult<C, 4> operator[](int m) {
        return InitialPartialResult<C, 4>(*this, m);
    }

};
```

And seriously, please, don't use this and just stick with `operator()`. :) Cheers!

Comment: Except for looking horribly, this code is quite simple (just one template + one partial spec), but go ahead and ask if something is not clear.

Comment: The questioner has changed `operator()` to return `int` rather than `void`, so you can update `PartialResult<T, 0, Count>::operator[]` for that. I don't think `PartialResult` has enough template parameters, so the eventual return type can be another one :-)

Comment: Great answer, thank you @Kos.  I now wonder if it helps to use `boost::tuple` for argument types (if different) and value.  I seem to remember reading somewhere that there is a way to call a function with parameters 'exploded' from a tuple...? edit: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/invocation/functions/invoke.html

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid this altogether and offer just `operator()`, but if you really want to give it a shot, the idea is that your type's `operator[]` would return an object of a helper type that holds both a reference to your object and the value that was passed in. That helper class will implement `operator[]` by again storing a reference to the original object and the arguments to both calls to `[]`. This would have to be done for all but the last level (I.e. a fair amount of helpers). I the last level, `operator[]` will take its argument together with all previously stored values and call `operator()` with all of the previously stored values plus the current value.

A common way of phrasing this is saying that each intermetiate type *binds* one of the arguments of the call to `operator()`, with the last one executing the call with all bound arguments.

Depending on whether you want to support more or less number of dimensions of arrays you might want/need to complicate this even more to make it generic. In general it is not worth the effort and just offering `operator()` is usually the solution. Remember that it is better to keep things as simple as possible: less effort to write and much less effort to maintain.

Comment: Indeed `operator()` is what I'm using right now.  Calling code is almost a domain-specific language though and the `[][][][]` syntax reads much easier in that context.

Comment: "need to ago placate" - writing on a phone?

Comment: I'd not heard it remarked before, but binding arguments is a very good description of what the helper class does.  Which makes me wonder: would it be possible somehow to use `boost::bind` to make the implementation trivial?  (I don't have time at the moment to experiment.  But the idea sounds reasonable.)

Comment: @James: I started writing an answer along those lines, but there were some fiddly bits that I don't have time to figure out how to do nicely. I'll post it anyway, as a start if anyone can fix it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: kind of...iPad. I have just moved to NY from Spain and still haven't got a computer. I hate autocorrect in the iPad with a passion. Regarding the `bind` I even condidered trying to compile/run a test program over SSH with the iPad, but I am not **that** crazy.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt at the `bind` approach. I doubt that it's particularly efficient, and it has some nasty bits in it, but I post it in case anyone knows how to fix it. Please edit:

```
template <int N>
struct Helper {
    function_type<N>::type f;
    explicit Helper(function_type<N>::type f) : f(f) {}
    Helper<N-1> operator[](int p) {
        return Helper<N-1>(bound<N-1>(f,p));
    }
};

template<>
struct Helper<0> {
    function_type<0>::type f;
    explicit Helper(function_type<0>::type f) : f(f) {}
    operator int() {
        return f();
    }
};

Helper<3> S::operator[](int p) {
    return Helper<3>(std::bind(s, _1, _2, _3));
}
```

where `s` is an expression that returns `operator()` bound to `this`. Something along the lines of `std::bind(std::mem_fun(S::operator(), this, _1, _2, _3, _4))`. Although I can't remember whether `std::bind` can already handle member functions, `mem_fun` might not be needed.

`function_type<N>::type` is `std::function<int, [int, ... n times]>`, and `bound<N>` is `function_type<N>::type bound(function_type<N+1>::type f, int p) { return std::bind(f, p, _1, _2, ... _N); }`. I'm not immediately sure how to define those recursively, but you could just list them up to some limit.

Comment: It would be easier if `std::bind` and `std::function` weren't black boxes and you could access the parameter types and values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Fusion implementation that supports arbitrary parameter and return types.  Kudos to anyone that can get this working (please let me know if you do)!

```
template <class Derived, class ReturnValue, class Sequence>
struct Bracketeer
{
    typedef ReturnValue result_type;
    typedef boost::fusion::result_of::size<Sequence> Size;

    struct RvBase
    {
        Sequence sequence;
        Derived *derived;
    };

    template <int n>
    struct Rv : RvBase
    {
        Rv(Derived *d) { this->derived = d; }
        Rv(RvBase *p) : RvBase(*p) { }
        Rv<n-1> operator[](typename boost::fusion::result_of::at_c<Sequence const, n-1>::type v)
        {
            boost::fusion::at_c<Size::value - 1 - n>(sequence) = v;
            return Rv<n-1>(this);
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct Rv<0> : RvBase
    {
        Rv(Derived *d) { this->derived = d; }
        Rv(RvBase *p) : RvBase(*p) { }
        ReturnValue operator[](typename boost::fusion::result_of::at_c<Sequence, Size::value - 1>::type v)
        {
            boost::fusion::at_c<Size::value - 1>(sequence) = v;
            return invoke(*derived, sequence);
        }
    };

    Rv<Size::value - 1> operator[](typename boost::fusion::result_of::at_c<Sequence, 0>::type v)
    {
        Rv<Size::value> rv(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
        return rv[v];
    }
};

struct S
    :
    Bracketeer<S, int, boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int, int> >
{
    int operator()(int a, int b, int c, int d);
};
```